# How to stream XDK 110 data via MAM

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging, sensor

I just got my Bosch XDK 110 and have been playing with the workbench. Everything works smoothly. Now I want  to stream this data via MAM to the Tangle. Are there any pointers on how should I do this? Maybe someone already did this? I would love not to reinvent the wheel if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across this implementation

https://antonionardella.it/mqtt-data-on-the-tangle-with-mam/

Comment: Can you give some more information, describe what it does and so forth. Stack Exchange answers shouldn't just be links.